# Como ver estatística do Git com Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Eu já usei o **GitHub** e o **GitLab** por um bom tempo. Essas plataformas são ricas em estatísticas, desde contribuições dos usuários, frequência dos commits e etc.

Mas agora estou fazendo parte de um projeto no **Bitbucket**, porém não encontrei nenhuma estatística disponível. Alguém sabe se realmente a plataforma não tem tal funcionalidade ou é eu que estou cego? Será que preciso usar alguma ferramenta de terceiro para isso?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu pesquisei agora, alguns usuários acham o **Bitbucket** inferior ao **Github** por que ele ainda não tem estas funcionalidades de estatísticas.

Mas, existe um plugin que dá algumas estatísticas para você

https://bitbucket.org/blog/awesome-graphs-for-bitbucket-visualized-statistics-for-git-and-mercurial-repositories?_ga=2.240342596.651384084.1546015395-1098061552.1546015395

E, se você quiser ler esta discussão que foi aberta por um dos desenvolvedores da Atlassian, que o pedido de desenvolvimento destas funcionalidades foi negado pelo chefe do time, acho

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/4307/feature-request-contributor-statistics-bb